# Transitive relationships

Tags: relationships

Does anyone know a way to find transitive relationships in civicrm?

Something like:
 ContactA is related to ContactB
 ContactB is related to ContactC

So ContactA is related to ContactC

Answer (score 1):

Best approach for a Drupal based CiviCRM would be using Views which is a Drupal module, then you can build up search/displays that will daisy-chain the relationships the way you describe.